# How to enable the compression option in a REST service

Tags: json, web-services, rest, resteasy

I am developing a REST service using rest-easy framework. My data is huge and its in application/json format.

I tried enabling the compression by annotating my service method by @GZIP.

But I find no difference in time difference at client side. With or without @GZIP annotation the time of response is same.

I am sending a HTTP get request and response is list of Objects in JSON format.

Is there anything else I need to do to achieve the compression while sending the response back to client?

Comment: You won't be looking for time difference, you will be looking for size difference. In Chrome's network tab (developer tools) you will see a size column, the top number is the transfer size and the bottom number is the actual size (uncompressed). https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer#text-compression-with-gzip

Comment: The whole reason why I am compressing the data , so that client can receive faster. Am I missing something here. Does it mean only compression will reduce the size to be transferred over network but since client needs to un compress so overall time will remain same. I somehow find it strange. I thought compression is done to make the response faster.

Comment: Usually it should be faster because you should save more time in receiving a smaller amount of data then you'll loose on uncompressing. But this depends on the kind and amount of data and the capabilities of the client. But you did not answer pherris question: Do the transfer and the actual size differ?

Comment: @pherris  yes the size & time differ when I use chrome to test my service. But when i use a jersey client the time remains same , I am still figuring out why may be I need to set the client header to request for compressed response ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What goes into downloading a file?**

The time in Chrome's network tools includes more than just downloading the file - if you mouseover the block in the Timeline column of the Network tab you'll see something like the image below. This shows that of the 1.32 seconds taken, only about 70ms is content download:

[image: Chrome's network tab]

Holy smokes 1.05 seconds for DNS lookup?! Must be my VPN. Note that the TTFB (time to first byte) is how long it took your server to start responding.

**How much time should you save?**

Another thing to keep in mind is that you're not going to save *that* much time with GZIP (I just lost my shot at working for Google with that statement!). The download time between 200 kb and 100 kb is way less than a second with a 5 mbps connection (that's pretty slow these days).

200 kb is 1,600,000 bits or 1.6 megabits so on a 5 megabit connection you're looking at `1.6/5 = 0.32` (or 320 ms to download). If you enable GZIP and drop the file size to 120 kb, you're looking at 0.96 megabits or 192 ms to download, a savings of 128 ms (respectable, but maybe not on the order of magnitude you were thinking?).

Using the image above as an example, we see that the calculated time is not exactly what you will see in the 'real world' because there are other things going on as the file is being exchanged (server bandwidth, networking oddities etc). The file in the image above is 32.9 kb, 0.2632 megabits which should take 52.64 ms, but actually took 70.437, but it's close. Feel free to correct my math, I am sure there is a mistake somewhere ;)

**What about server time?**

Finally, you may want to look into the amount of time taken to *generate* the file - if your server is taking 5s to generate it and 800ms on a 5 mbps connection to transfer, you probably can't improve things as much as you want with GZIP (maybe 400 ms max) so your total time will still be high at 5.4 s and the real issue is the time the server is taking to generate the file.

Comment: Thanks @pherris , I changed my client to send the encoding as gzip.deflate and I could see some improvements. But as you pointed out its not as much as I expected. The time to compress and uncompress using Gzip had eaten away a major portion of time. Can I do better if I use some other compression method , What I need to do for that ? Which other option I should try ?

Comment: How big is your file (compressed/uncompressed)? What time are you getting (what do you want to see)? What type of connection are you on? I would hesitate to go another route besides GZIP without a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything else, the compression is enabled with @GZIP.
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/gzip.html

Comment: Yes , I referred this process , but my question is why client doesn't receive the data faster ?